# how to make app working when is closed (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm start building alarm app need make it alert user by notification
but notification can't work when app is closed
so , how to send local notification when app is closed (React Native android & ios) ?

Comment: iOS app can send local notification which with a date in the future which will be activated even if the app is close.